# How do I put a hashmap through a for each loop (that would allow for multiple hashmaps to be put through)?

Tags: java, hashmap

So I am trying to create a project on Code Academy, and I have been working on the past code for awhile. Basically, I have put books into a program that will tell me which ones have been completed and which have not been. To do so, I create a HashMap with them later on in the code. I keep getting problems with the for each loop (where it should check if the book is read or not and then print the ones that are completed), and I think there is a problem with me defining the specific variables later in the code (but I have created the object earlier)... maybe? Anyways, here is my code. Can anyone see what's wrong with it?

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Library {

    public Library() {
    }

    public void getFinishedBooks(HashMap<String, Boolean> library) {
        if (library.size() < 1) {
            System.out.println("Error, HashMap is empty.");
        } else {

            for (HashMap<String, Boolean> entry : library.entrySet()) {
                String key = entry.getKey();
                Boolean value = entry.getValue();
                if (value) {
                    System.out.println(key);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashMap<String, Boolean> myBooks = new HashMap<String, Boolean>();
        myBooks.put("Road Down The Funnel", true);
        myBooks.put("Rat: A Biology", false);
        myBooks.put("TimeIn", true);
        myBooks.put("3D Food Printing", false);
        Library myLibrary = new Library();
        myLibrary.getFinishedBooks(myBooks);

    }
}
```

Thank you!!

Comment: pls copy your code into the edit window, then mark it and press the code button, it will leave the formatting intact.

Comment: Apart from the answers below, you could structure your classes better. Let the Library class save the books as a private variable(inside a hashmap). You can have a different method for pushing the books and read status in. Otherwise there is no reason to have the library class. You could also make the getFinishedBooks method static. Instead of declaring the variable as 'HashMap', you could declare it as the interface 'Map' and pass the HashMap instance to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change HashMap with Entry, in this line:

```
for (Entry<String, Boolean> entry : library.entrySet())
```

library.entrySet() returns Map.Entry, not HashMap.

Comment: When I try that, it says an error that it could not find the symbol. 
  symbol:   class Entry
  location: class Library
1 error

Comment: import java.util.Map.Entry;  just dont forget to import it :)

Comment: I tested your code after my change, works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#entrySet()), Map#entrySet returns a Set of Entrys, but in your for-each loop you try to convert it into a HashMap

Answer (score 0):

change your code to following code inside getFinishedBooks()

```
for(Entry<String, HashMap> entry : library.entrySet()) {
    String key = entry.getKey();
    Boolean value = entry.getValue();
    if (value) 
    {
         System.out.println(key);
    }
}
```